# Drag and Drop feature to copy one buttons text to another buttons text

Tags: android, drag-and-drop

I want to make an app which will copy the text of one button to the text of another button when a button is dragged and dropped on other button. I am totally novice, I have Googled but not found anything easy to understand.

Answer (score 0):

You should add [onDragListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnDragListener.html)
to views. And use [startDrag](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#startDrag(android.content.ClipData,%20android.view.View.DragShadowBuilder,%20java.lang.Object,%20int)) method on views. You can find more information in [Drag and Drop | Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/drag-drop.html).

Basically you attach a drag listener to view which you can set reponses up to action types. Drag listener is triggered from views you started dragging by `startDrag(...)` referenced above. You can find a detailed example in this [link](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidDragAndDrop/article.html). Once you read & understand it, all you need to do is copying your button's text to other one in ACTION_DROP.

Set your onDragListener to all your buttons & in `onLongClick()` ( I prefer to start drag on long click rather than on click, when to start drag is totally up to your liking ) use `startDrag(...)`. Button you are dragging will trigger `onDragListener(...)` which you attached to buttons.

I recommend you to read above example carefully, `onDragListener(...)` sounds like It works when you drag view that you attached It to, but It's actually works when views that you `startDrag(...)` enters bounds of view you attached It to.